# iOS lazy-loading of table images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

I have successfully implemented lazy-loading of images in my app using the example provided by apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). The thing is that, I want the image to load as I am scrolling, but the image loads into the cell only when I finish dragging (Release my finger from the screen. Until then the cell remains empty). I have modified the code as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //NSLog(@"cell for row at indexpath, size - %f, current - %d", flowTable.contentSize.height, self.current);

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FlowCell";

    MyFlowCell *cell = (MyFlowCell *)[self.flowTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FlowCell" owner:nil options:nil];
       // cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        for(id currentObject in nib)

        {

        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[MyFlowCell class]])

        {
            cell = (MyFlowCell *)currentObject;

            break;
        }
        }
    }

    ImageDetails *rowItem = [self.imageData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (!rowItem.mainImage)
    {  
       // if (self.flowTable.dragging == NO && self.flowTable.decelerating == NO)
       // {

            [self startIconDownload:rowItem forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //}

        cell.mainImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    }
    else
    {

            cell.mainImage.image = rowItem.mainImage;

    }
    }


    return cell;
}


- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate)
    {
      //  [self loadImagesForOnscreenRows];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //[self loadImagesForOnscreenRows];
}
```

Moreover, I found out that in my ImageDownloader class, the NSURLConnection doesn't even receive the response until I release my finger from the screen. I have been trying to find out why this is happening, but I haven't been successful so far. Please tell me if I've been missing something.

Comment: This may help you [MJTableImageSwift](https://github.com/JaleelNazir/MJTableImageSwift)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve lazy loading in your tableview by following these steps :

In your Class.h, put:

```
NSMutableDictionary *Dict_name;
BOOL isDragging_msg, isDecliring_msg;
```

Now In Class.m file, put this code in view did load:

```
Dict_name = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if ([dicImages_msg valueForKey:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image name or image link"]]) { 
    cell.image_profile.image=[dicImages_msg valueForKey:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image name or image link"]];
}
else
{
    if (!isDragging_msg && !isDecliring_msg)
    {
        [dicImages_msg setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"] forKey:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image name or image link"]];
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadImage_3:) withObject:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.image_profile.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];
    }
}
```

And for the download image the function is:

```
-(void)downloadImage_3:(NSIndexPath *)path{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pl = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *str=[here Your image link for download];

    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]]]; 

    [dicImages_msg setObject:img forKey:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"image name or image link same as cell for row"]];

    [tableview performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    [pl release];
}
```

And at last put these methods in your class:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    isDragging_msg = FALSE;     
    [tableview reloadData];
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    isDecliring_msg = FALSE;
    [tableview reloadData]; 
}
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    isDragging_msg = TRUE;
}
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    isDecliring_msg = TRUE; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, that demonstrates one solid technique (though using `reloadData` is an inefficient way to update the cell).

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks a LOT for all your answers. Each one helped me in its own way to solve the problem. I mostly used the concept of this post, though. So just for the sake of it, I will accept this one. :)

Answer (score 9):

Updated answer:

The standard Apple [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) suffers from a few flaws:

1. It won't try to retrieve the images until the scrolling finished. I understand why they chose to do that (probably don't want to retrieve images that might be scrolling away), but this causes the images to appear more slowly than necessary.
2. It does not constrain the number of concurrent requests to some reasonable number. Yes, `NSURLConnection` will automatically freeze requests until the maximum number of requests falls to some reasonable number, but in a worst case scenario, you can actually have requests time out, as opposed to simply queueing properly.
3. Once it starts to download the image, it won't cancel it even if the cell subsequently scrolls off of the screen.

The simple fix is to retire `IconDownloader` and all of the scrolling/decelerating logic and just use the `UIImageView` category from either [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

If you're going to fix this yourself, it takes a little work to get all of this right. But [here is a rendition of LazyTableImages](https://github.com/robertmryan/LazyTableImages) that uses `NSOperationQueue` to ensure that we (a) limit concurrent requests; and (b) allows us to cancel requests. I confess I prefer the above `UIImageView` category implementations, better, but I tried to stay with the structure of Apple's original `LazyTableImages`, while remedying the flaws I've enumerated above.

Comment: My original answer employed Grand Central Dispatch to simplify the Apple LazyTableImages code. But it didn't solve many of the structural problems of this original implementation, so my revised answer addresses those points.

Comment: The linked GitHub project does not resolve the waiting for end scrolling. The SDWebImage does instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your UITableViewCell has an url property and a UIImage property for the image (plus a property or static value for the queue:

```
- (void) setThumbnailUrlString:(NSString *)urlString
{
    thumbnailUrlString = urlString;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    if ( queue == nil )
    {
        queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    }
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * resp, NSData     *data, NSError *error) 
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ 
                       {
                            if ( error == nil && data )
                            {
                                UIImage *urlImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                thumbnail.image = urlImage;
                            }
                       });
    }];
}
```

The issue with your implementation is that your image loading method is probably occurring in the main thread. You need to load the image asynchronously and then update the image in the main thread.

To be correct the block should check to see if the response's url matches the requested url if the cell's image loaded too late before the cell was reused for a different image.

Comment: queue is a NSOperationQueue btw

Comment: BTW, you don't need to create this operation queue. You can just use `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` as the `queue` parameter to `sendAsynchronousRequest`. The request still happens asynchronously, but the completion block will be called on the main queue, thus eliminating the need for that `dispatch_async` to the main queue. The `queue` parameter of `sendAsynchronousRequest` is the queue for the completion block, not for the request itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this framework which contains lazy load controller. It's easy to use and works out of the box.
https://github.com/cloverstudio/CSUtils
Tutorial can be found here:
http://www.clover-studio.com/blog/using-csutils-ios-framework-for-lazy-loading-images/

Answer (score 0):

This is quite late answer, but with iOS version changes the approach keeps changing.

In order to lazily load the images, here is the recommended approach:

1. Download URLs of all images and store them into your container (array / objects etc)
2. Fire a [NSURLSessionTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/) (post iOS 7 only) which runs async on background queue. If you are below iOS 7, you can use [NSURLConnection SendAsynchronousRequest API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:) - it's deprecated in iOS 9 so you better get rid of that soon.
3. Create your images while on background queue
4. Come back to main queue, ensure that you got the right UITableViewCell, then update the image

Here - the entire approach is [described in my tutorial](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/ios-app-design-blog-load-images-asynchronously-inside-uitableview/).